# How to replace a specific "word" with value of a variable in unix/sed...etc.?

Tags: unix, sed

I'd want to do this:

```
sed -i 's#cellname#$cell#g' file.txt
```

I meant to replace all "cellname" words with the value of variable $cell instead of "$cell" text.

ex: $cell = nand4

then after sed, file.txt will contains word "nand4" instead of "cellname"

Comment: I've found a solution to my question already.                                            sed -i 's#cellname#'$cell'#g' file.txt

Comment: This is a way, since you are closing the quotes and then opening again. However, I would go for `sed -i "s#cellname#$cell#g" file.txt`. That is, using double quotes like the duplicate suggests.

Comment: And when you stick with your solution, put double quotes around $cell, so it will not break when the value of cell has a space: `sed -i 's#cellname#'"$cell"'#g' file.txt`